# Was Saturn a person or god among the early Romans?

Tags: roman

I've been very perplexed over the confusing matter regarding Saturn and how he was viewed by the early Romans. Some say he was a just king who ruled the Romans in a golden age, succeeding Janus. Others claim Saturn was a god.

Then who was Jupiter Latiaris? What if any connection exists between the very primitive acknowledgement of Jupiter being supreme on the one hand and the cults of Saturn on the other?

Answer (score 7):

In ancient Rome, there was a divine trio known as the [Archaic Triad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitoline_Triad). The members were Jupiter, Mars,and [Quirinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirinus).

Saturn is possibly derived from [Satre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satre_(Etruscan_god)), an Etruscan god mentioned on a bronze tablet called the [Liver of Piacenza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liver_of_Piacenza).

Others disagree, claiming Saturn was originally an ancient Etruscan king, whose reign was a Golden Age. The king's name was Saturnus.

Comment: Almost nothing is known about Quirinus. He was associated with the myrtle.